# How to set Cryptography Service Provider for keystore using java

Tags: java, service, cryptography, keystore, provider

Using openssl shell command I can pass -CSP parameter to define a custom provider when exporting a pkcs12 file.

For example:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in "${DIR}/${NAME}.crt"  -passin pass:"${PASSWD_KEY}" -passout pass:"${PASSWD_KEY}" -inkey "${DIR}/${NAME}.key" -name "${NAME}" -certfile ${CAFILES} -CSP "ECDSA_p256#Microsoft Software Key Service Provider" -out "${DIR}/${NAME}.p12"

I need to set this provider for a keystore generated using Java API and bouncy castle. 
I'am using Keystore and X509v3CertificateBuilder classes.

How can I set the provider when generating the pkcs12 with the Java API?

Note: 
I know the Keystore.getInstance method receives a String specifying a provider but, this string represents a bouncy castle style provider instead of a provider to enable the use of Elliptic Curves in windows applications.

Comment: You need this why?

Comment: In order to use elliptic curves cryptography algorithm in a .Net application using a PKCS12 keystore created with Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to set the Microsoft CSP property, you have to do this:

```
PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier bagAttr = (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier)privateKey; 
bagAttr.setBagAttribute( 
MicrosoftObjectIdentifiers.microsoft.branch("17").branch("1"), 
new DERBMPString("ECDSA_P256#Microsoft Software key Service Provider"));
```